# How to group Push Messages on Android

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to group my push messages on my android device. I want to have it working like whatsapp. If there are more than 1 message, keep the title (if they are the same), but show the number of messages in a certain "thread".

My app has something like a chat room. And I want to collect all messages for a single room and show e.g. Chat Room A as title and then the number of new messages in there. As soon as there is a new post in another chat room, I want it to say something like "6 new messages in 2 chat rooms".

Unfortunately I have no idea how to achieve something like this with GCM on Android.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with GCM.

You have to handle the notification area like [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html). Here is the [official sample](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).